# How to round off to 2 decimal places for double variables?

Tags: java, android, double

For the shipping fees and sub total, I have declared it as `double`. However 
   they just display an amount of `25.0` or `128.0` with just one decimal. I wish to display `25.00` or `128.00` instead. How should I modify my code?

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Refresh the data
    if(mProductAdapter != null) {
        mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    double totalweight = 0;
    double shippingfee = 0;
    for(product p : mCartList) {
        int quantity = ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(p);
        totalweight += p.weight * quantity;
        shippingfee = ShoppingCartActivity.getShipping(totalweight);
    }

    double subTotal = 0;
    for(product p : mCartList) {
        int quantity = ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(p);
        subTotal += p.price * quantity;
    }
    if (subTotal >= 150){
        shippingfee = 0;
        subTotal += shippingfee;
    }
    else{
        for(product p : mCartList) {
            int quantity = ShoppingCartActivity.getProductQuantity(p);
            totalweight += p.weight * quantity;
            shippingfee = ShoppingCartActivity.getShipping(totalweight);
        }
        subTotal += shippingfee;
    }
    TextView productPriceTextView = (TextView) 
    findViewById(R.id.TextViewSubtotal);
    productPriceTextView.setText("Subtotal: RM" + subTotal);
    TextView productWeightTextView = (TextView) 
    findViewById(R.id.TextViewSubweight);
    productWeightTextView.setText("Shipping Weight: " + totalweight +" kg");
    TextView productShippingTextView = (TextView) 
    findViewById(R.id.TextViewShipping);
    productShippingTextView.setText("Shipping Fee: RM" + shippingfee);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use [floating point for money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) anyway. Probably [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) would be better.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to round it to a '00' value, you can format it as such

```
String value = String.format("%.2f",price);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```